# How do I render complex json into Jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jstree

I am trying to render complex json into jstree. But jstree is not accepting my json for some reason. My JSON is as follows. Please tell me how can I make a tree out of this json.  I've tried using a basic JSON data, but it takes that. When I have nested children it seems to fail. Ive feeded this data into JSTree but its not rendering anything.

```
$(function() {
        var Collection = {
"toc": {
    "_version": "1",
    "_lang": "en",
    "_icon": "/icon/tfu.png",
    "_display_name": "science_1",
    "_learning_engine": "disabled",
    "_grade": "1",
    "_curriculum": "CBSE",
    "ge": [
        {
            "_display_name": "You and Your Surroundings",
            "_id": "5b7b8883ff0f25785592a6db",
            "_icon": "tfu.png",
            "_learning_status": "0",
            "_unlocked": false,
            "ge": [
                {
                    "_display_name": "Our Surroundings",
                    "_id": "5b7b8883ff0f25785592a6dc",
                    "_learning_status": "0",
                    "_unlocked": false,
                    "ge": [
                        {
                            "_display_name": "Our Surroundings",
                            "_id": "e121076",
                            "_icon": "thumbnails/e121076.png",
                            "_demo_content": false,
                            "_learning_status": "0",
                            "_unlocked": false,
                            "_notes": true,
                            "_description": "This topic describes our surroundings.",
                            "ce": [
                                {
                                    "_display_name": "Objectives",
                                    "_banner": "banner/objectives/",
                                    "_id": "5b7b8883ff0f25785592a6de",
                                    "_type": "objectives",
                                    "_url": "lessonoutcome/e121076.json",
                                    "flow_rule": "usage = 500"
                                },
                                {
                                    "_display_name": "Our Surroundings",
                                    "_id": "e121076",
                                    "_icon": "icon/video.png",
                                    "_CEW": 10,
                                    "_RE": 5,
                                    "_type": "video",
                                    "_min_eff_time": 300,
                                    "_max_eff_time": 600,
                                    "_url": "secure_video/success/e121076_our_surroundings_B2C_US.mp4 ",
                                    "flow_rule": "usage = 500"
                                },
                                {
                                    "_display_name": "Activity 1",
                                    "_id": "5b7b8883ff0f25785592a6e0",
                                    "_type": "html_activity",
                                    "_url": "e121076/Activity1/index.html",
                                    "flow_rule": "usage = 500",
                                    "no_instructions": false
                                },
                                {
                                    "_display_name": "Activity 2",
                                    "_id": "5b7b8883ff0f25785592a6e1",
                                    "_type": "html_activity",
                                    "_url": "e121076/Activity2/index.html",
                                    "flow_rule": "usage = 500",
                                    "no_instructions": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "_display_name": "Activity 3",
                                    "_id": "5b7b8883ff0f25785592a6e2",
                                    "_type": "html_activity",
                                    "_url": "e121076/Activity3/index.html",
                                    "flow_rule": "usage = 500",
                                    "no_instructions": true
                                },
                                {
                                    "_display_name": "Challenge Test",
                                    "_id": "5b7b8883ff0f25785592a6e3",
                                    "_type": "challenge_test",
                                    "_url": "e121076",
                                    "flow_rule": "usage = 500"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "ce": {
                        "_display_name": "Practice Test",
                        "_id": "5b7b8883ff0f25785592a6dc_CT",
                        "_type": "practice_quiz",
                        "_url": [
                            "e121076"
                        ],
                        "flow_rule": "usage = 500",
                        "_demo_content": false,
                        "no_instructions": true
                    }
                }
            ],
            "ce": {
                "_display_name": "Challenge Test",
                "_id": "5b7b8883ff0f25785592a6db_CT",
                "_type": "challenge_test",
                "_url": [
                    "e121076"
                ],
                "flow_rule": "usage = 500",
                "_demo_content": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

After this json, I'm trying to render it using;

```
$('#data').jstree({
    'core' : {
        'check_callback' : true,
        'data' :arrayCollection ,
    }
```

Comment: and what happens when you do that? What errors and/or unexpected behaviour do you experience? (Hint: "it's not working" is not the answer we are looking for :-))

Comment: jsTree expects JSON in a specific structure and expects certain key-value pairs. You will have to convert your existing structure to something jsTree understands.

Comment: Any Idea how to  convert my JSON to jstree JSON?

Comment: The structure is a bit confusing as what represents child nodes here ? What do the keys 'ge' & 'ce' denote ?